# character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_general_ci does not accept words with accents

Tags: mysql

I have a database with the character set configured for utf8mb4 and collate as utf8mb4_general_ci but when I run the command

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TESTE(
  CAMPO VARCHAR(200)
 );


INSERT INTO TESTE (CAMPO) VALUES ('é');

select * from TESTE;
```

it returns me the error

```
1 Incorrect string value: '\xE9' for column 'CAMPO' at row 9 SQL1.sql 9 20
```

what happens is that I am using a LOAD DATA INFILE to INSERT values ​​in my database and I need my table to accept accented characters

Answer (score 0):

I run this in mysql 8.0.19 and as you see in 5.7

> ```
> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TESTE(
>   CAMPO VARCHAR(200) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci
>  );
>
>
> INSERT INTO TESTE (CAMPO) VALUES ('é');
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select * from TESTE;
> ```
>
> ```
> | CAMPO |
> | :---- |
> | é    |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=4817393808d81839783ba2787b9431bc)*

both work just fine.

check your database, Table/column somewhere you don't have the right characterset

Answer (score 0):

Had to change the character set of the values that i was INSERTING on my table to latin1

I was using

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'pathToMyFile.csv' 
INTO TABLE myTable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
```

so i had to add the command `CHARACTER SET latin1`
soo my code now is like

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'pathToMyFile.csv' 
INTO TABLE myTable
CHARACTER SET latin1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
```

and worked fine.